# Name of the tool to simulate packets on Cisco

Tags: cisco

On the CONSOLE of a Cisco router there was a command to create a "simulated packet", to check if it gets routed or not. It showed the internal steps the router would follow. It was great for debugging!

It is NOT the windows application PacketTracer, nor GNS, it is just a command inside the IOS. I have been googling around and I cannot find it.

Does anybody remember the command name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ASA firewall, it is:

```
packet-tracer input <INTERFACE> <PROTO> <SOURCE_IP> <SOURCE_PORT> <DEST_IP> <DEST_PORT> [detailed] [xml]
```

For example:

```
packet-tracer input INSIDE tcp 192.168.1.1 12345 10.1.1.1 80 detailed
```

It *might* be the same for one of their routers...

Comment: yes!  but it seems my 2811 don't have it :-(

Comment: Yeah, I only ever found it in the ASA firewall line.  I've missed it in other Cisco products...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a ping command. You can adjust ping parameters (such as packet size, protocol, outgoing interface and so on).

Comment: It was more advanced -- you could select the ports, IP addresses, protocol, etc -- and more importantly it was "virtual" so the packet did never exist.